# jQuery Script not working in IE7 (HTML5 Doctype)

Tags: jquery

The following image swapper code is not working in IE7. I tried everytihng I could thinbk of to no avail.

Working sample here: http://www.bcsstaging.com/lamaze-intimates/bras.php

**Here is the jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //Setup each produce switcher on the page
    $(".item").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".preview .thumbnails").show();
        var imgTitle = $(this).find(".thumbnails img:first-child").attr("title");   
        $(this).find("a:first").addClass("active");
        $(this).find(".caption").html(imgTitle);        
    });

    //Update Image on Click
    $(".thumbnails a img").click(function(){            
        var navParent = $(this).parent().parent();
        var itemParent = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        var imgTitle = $(this).attr("title");
        var previewImg = $(itemParent).find("img.main");            
        var link = $(this).parent();    
        var linkHref = link.attr("href");           
        var linkAlt = link.attr("alt");         

        if( $(link).hasClass("active") == false)
        {
            $(navParent).find("a").removeClass("active");
            link.addClass("active");                                            
            $(previewImg).animate({
                opacity: 0.8,
            }, 300, function() {
                if(imgTitle != "") $(itemParent).find(".caption").html(imgTitle);
                previewImg.attr("src", linkHref);               
                previewImg.attr("alt", linkAlt);                
                $(this).animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    }, 300
                );                          
            });         
        }
        return false;
    });
    $("input").click(function(){
        $("p.more").fadeIn("slow");
    })
});
```

Comment: try this `.ie7 * { opacity: inherit; filter: inherit; }`

Comment: Try removing that comma after both opacity declarations (e.g. change "opacity: 0.8," to "opacity: 0.8"). IE is sensitive about those things. Did you see any errors in the dev console?

Comment: @Raminson unfortunately it didn't do it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ingo I tried removing the commas that too didn't do it. Companion.js in IE7 is telling me the error is in that area. Line#93 (In my version) which is **}, 300, function() {** it is telling me there is a syntax error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Tried refreshing cache after deleting those commas? That syntax error looks like it's because of that comma after "0.8"

Comment: Yeah I cleared the cache. In fact I updated the link with the comma removed and tested on a remote IE7 to be sure. I tried variations with the commas in and out for both the 0.8 and the 300 It's a weird one.

Comment: What about this one on the later opacity "opacity: 1,". Tried removing that as well?

Comment: I did try that too. Thanks again for your work Ingo.

Comment: `:first-child` is suspicious, could it be this http://robertnyman.com/2009/02/04/how-to-solve-first-child-css-bug-in-ie-7/ ?

Comment: In the end it was the actual CSS opacity syntax. IE8 and earlier need to be like this: **filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was the actual CSS opacity syntax.

**IE8 and earlier need to be like this:**

```
filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
```